# Same script is called twice, with different params, and they are not accepted

Tags: javascript, html

I am using in the same page `<script src="xxx.js?hi=1" ></script>`
and `<script src="xxx.js" ></script>`

Problem is, in the script itself when i ask for the params, i dont see the hi=1 even though it sent it... can it be cache??

thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by you don't "see" it? Could you elaborate and post the code you're using to check the value of the GET parameter?

Comment: You have to process the request on the server side somehow. Just calling *any* with a GET parameter attached does not make this parameter available to the file.

Comment: I parse the querystring and i dont get the hi=1

Comment: How do you parse the query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my experience, the browser should load the script twice...  but when you say the script doesn't see the `hi=1`, you do mean the script on the server, right?  Because the Javascript returned won't be able to see that.  It is the server side that gets the request to send back any content that sees it.  So in your PHP or whatever language you are using on the server side, print out the params, and you should be able to see it.

And you can "spit out" different Javascript content depending on the params that the server script sees.

Answer (score 0):

No. Different URIs are different URIs, the browser doesn't cache if the difference is only in the query string. This won't be a caching issue.

The problem is most likely either in how you try to access the query string, or that you use globals in the script and the two copies are overwriting each other's data.